# When the page gets redirected, I am getting default Angular Icon in the addressbar in IE

Tags: angular, favicon

I have added my favicon to the index.html and in angular.json give an error under assets as below:

```
"assets": [
   "src/assets/img/favicon.ico",             
   "src/images",
   "src/css",
]
```

---

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/img/favicon.ico">
```

For the login Page I see my correct logo but after logged in I am getting default Angular Icon in the address bar

Comment: can you show index.html?

Comment: <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/img/favicon.ico">

Comment: can be a cache issue, do Ctrl + R if you go to developer tools (Network tab) and then open the favicon.ico from there, do you get the latest icon or the old angular-icon?

Comment: I am not getting favicon.ico itself in the network tab to open it

Comment: What version of Angular are you using?